# Как работает аллокация памяти в контейнерах STL?

Tags: c++, stl

У меня есть двухсвязный список std::list как protected обьект в классе A:

```
class A {
  public:
    std::list<int> list;
}
```

в main я динамически выделяю память под обьект класса A и додаю 3 integer после чего освобождаю память

```
int main() {
  A* a = new A();
  a.list.push_back(1);
  a.list.push_back(2);
  a.list.push_back(3);
  delete a;
  return 1;
}
```

удалится ли list при delete? и как std::list аллоцирует память?

Comment: Конечно, delete просто вызывает деструктор у А. Так как вы не объявил другие конструкторы,то компилятор сгенерирует их сам.

Comment: MrBin, это я знаю, меня больше интересует как происходит аллокация памяти внутри самого std::list, он же не знает при компиляции сколько в него всунут елементов

Comment: @MikeWaters так ему и не нужно это знать: в списке выделение памяти происходит динамически по мере добавления новых данных.

Comment: @Andrej Levkovitch окей, как именно динамически? и когда происходит освобождение динамически выделеной памяти?

Comment: Когда вы удаляете элементы освобождается память. Не факт, что прям каждый раз, но иногда происходит. Также в деструкторе освобождается. После вызова деструктора класса, вызываются деструкторы всех полей этого класса.  После слов `delete a;`, вызывается пустой деструктор `A`, после чего уже не пустой деструктор `std::list<int>`, который и очищает память.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко только вопрос, что значит: не факт, что каждый раз.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, в стандарте stl в некоторых местах выделение памяти оставили на усмотрение разработчиков компилятора. std::list должен вести себя (с точки зрения расхода памяти и поддерживаемых операций) как двусвязный список, но это не означает, что там внутри обязан быть двусвязный список. По поводу удаления памяти. Это хорошо видно на примере std::vector. В качестве одного из вариантов реализации, память выделяется не каждую вставку, но выделяется сразу много. Например в 2 раза больше чем было. При удалении элементов из массива, память удаляется не сразу, а только когда её становится

Comment: В 4 раза больше, чем реально используется. Поэтому в std::vector есть метод shrink_to_fit, который удаляет не используемую память. Это позволяет делать вставку и удаление в среднем за o(1), хотя при вставке и удалении иногда происходит копирование всего массива.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко в 4 раза больше ни одна вменяемая реализация выделять не будет. Это число колеблется от 1 до 2. При удалении из вектора память вообще не освобождается. Никогда.

Comment: @ixSci, ну с 4 я может и перегнуть. При удалении из вектора память не удаляется? Это почему ещё? В стандарте такое не написано. Да и зачем так делать? P.s это было продолжение предыдущего комментария, не влез. Там предложение разодрано.

Comment: @ДмитрийЗиненко всё там написано. Частичное освобождение памяти невозможно, а полное освобождение вызовет релокацию и инвалидацию всех итераторов, что **не** описано в контракте метода `erase`.

Comment: @ixSci, да, вы правы

Answer (score 3):

Как `std::list` аллоцирует память совершенно не важно, важно только то, что для этого используется тот аллокатор, который передан ему в качестве аргумента шаблона (по умолчанию используется `std::allocator`). При разрушении объекта `std::list` он освобождает всю память которую выделил, а также вызывает деструкторы для каждого элемента, которые были в него добавлены.

Вышеописанное справедливо для любого контейнера стандартной библиотеки C++.